# Could someone help me with this physics problem about water pressure

Tags: design, hydrostatics, water-pressure

I am designing a rainwater collection system. Rainwater is initially collected in an open-top barrel equipped with filters and sensors. This barrel is connected to a pillow tank, a flexible water storage container. The pillow tank has an air valve on top and is meant to be filled solely with water. My question is, how much higher should the water level be in the barrel to completely fill the pillow tank, taking into account the weight of the top part of the pillow tank?

Is there a formula that considers variables like tank height, tank length, tank width, and the weight of the top part of the tank? This way, I can adjust these variables to find the best solution for different applications.[image]

Comment: `could someone help me?` is not an engineering question ... please ask about the problem, not about people's availability to assist

Comment: You need to figure out the pressure required to fill your pillow tank.  Some similar tanks (well tanks) have a membrane that is essentially there to apply a spring load to the water, and are intended only to be loaded to a rated pressure.  This load (to stretch) is what you are after, and you do not have enough details in your question for us to figure it out.  Pressure is pretty easy to convert to height of water based on density (height of water is even a common unit for pressure)

Comment: What about having the reservoir directly above the tank? like the water feeder for animals?

Comment: water will always seek its own level, so any delta over height of the tank will let it fill eventually.  The fill rate will be based on the pressure difference and pipe size (a 36" culvert would fill it immediately, a 1/4 inch tube would take quite a while)

Answer (score 1):

**Real Pillow Tank**

Typical soft-sided uncontained [pillow tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bladder_tank) have a $\lesssim 1$ [psi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_per_square_inch) pressure relief valve (PRV) at the centre of the top, which is the highest point when the tank is filled. (See, for example,  [here](https://tarpinnovators.com/fuel-water-storage) or [here](https://canflexinc.com/decontamination-cleaning-stations-secondary-fluid-containment-berms/) or [here](https://www.tanks.ie/10000-litre-bladder-water-tank-non-potable/p22130).) One psi corresponds to about 70 cm of water, so if your pillow tank has a 1 psi PRV, then it should completely fill to its maximum capacity if the water level in the barrel is about 70 cm above the top of the water in the pillow tank. Any more water and the PRV will release water, lowering the water level in the pillow and the barrel until the pressure at the top of the pillow tank is again less than 1 psi.

**Idealized Pillow Tank Formula**

If the pillow tank and barrel both had vertical sides (which is not the case for real pillow tanks and many barrels), then when the pillow lid is just resting on the water in the pillow tank and the tank sides are not in tension

$$\frac{m_\mathrm{water}}{A_\mathrm{barrel}}=\frac{M_\mathrm{water}+M_\mathrm{lid}}{A_{pillow}}$$

In other words, the pillow tank should completely fill as long as the mass of the water in the rainwater barrel ($m_\mathrm{water}$) divided by its (horizontal) cross-sectional area ($A_\mathrm{barrel}$) is greater than the mass of the pillow tank water ($M_\mathrm{water}$) plus the mass of its lid ($M_\mathrm{lid}$) divided by its cross-sectional area ($A_\mathrm{pillow}$).

I would be surprised if the weight of the top of the pillow tank was actually significant, since most pillow tanks are relatively thin (few mm thick) membranes with density very similar to water.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehenisve explanation and fomrmula. This was exactely what i needed :)